# Make Xamarin.Forms TabBar translucent on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

I want to make my TabBar in my Xamarin.Forms app translucent, like it's the default on iOS nowadays. But just setting `ios:TabbedPage.TranslucencyMode="Translucent"` like in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/tabbedpage-translucent-tabbar) didn't work. It also didn't work on the NavigationBar, but for that I could write a custom renderer that made it work. But I couldn't bring it to work for the TabBar.

This is the current behaviour:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keU3a.png). 
As you may see, the NavigationBar is perfectly translucent, but the TabBar is not.

[Here](https://github.com/julian-baumann/XamarinTestApp) is the project I use as reference in this question. You can see [here](https://github.com/julian-baumann/XamarinTestApp/blob/master/TestApp/TestApp.iOS/Renderers/NativeTabBarRenderer.cs) my attempt to make the TabBar translucent.

My Question: Does anyone has a functional TabBar custom-renderer that makes the TabBar on iOS translucent? 
Or can someone set me on the right track?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems it's impossible to make the Tabbar translucent, I've tried all the solution online but no luck.